# How do i place an image in the centre of a page horizontally?

Tags: html, css

Currently I have everything on the left hand side of the page. But I would like to begin changing it to the middle (just horizontally). But as i'm a beginner, each time i try it doesn't turn out right. Could someone with more experience help?

html:

```
   <div class="iphonecontainer">
   <img class="iphone" src="untitled.jpg" align="left">
   </div>
```

css:

```
   .iphonecontainer
   {
   width:100%;
   float:left;
   margin-top:6.5%;
   }

   .iphone {
   display:block;
   width: 400px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   }
```

Thanks for taking the time to help, have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change 
margin: 0; 
To 
Margin: 0px auto;
Update. Sorry yes remove the align: left.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. Take note that in my html code, the image also has the code, align=left. I should take that out completely or change to something else?

Comment: Try to avoid inline styles when you can. CSS is easier to maintain and make changes. See updated answer yes remove inline rule.

Comment: This worked, thanks very much :) and thanks for the tip i'll remember that for next time

Answer (score 0):

```css
.iphonecontainer
   {
   width:100%;
   text-align:center;
   margin:6.5% auto;
   }
```